# New to Arduino building

Tags: arduino-uno

I am new to Arduino an working with the Uno.  My dream is to activate servos in a perticular order once some type of sensor recognizes a live person near it.  Is their a perticular easy to understand book out there I can read?  There are lots and lots of books but they all get very complex rather quickly.  I'd be curious as to fellow inventors in here telling me how they mastered the Arduino?  Maybe it was not a book but rather a complete course.  Will others please respond to help me.  ps... I do have an electronics degree so I don't need soldering or component understanding.  I know what Vcc is.  I need please some type of course book which will take me now beyond the self blinking light into robotic control if that easy to understand book or course is out there.
Thank you.  Michael in Palm Beach, FL

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of examples on the official Arduino website.

My advice is you follow them, not only by reading, but buy the components you need (they are cheap) and practice and see how to handle them within the Arduino environment.

Do one component at a time (led, switch, Servo, Sensor), and focus on the servo/sensors you want to use.

Than try to combine multiple components, step by step until you have your dream project ready.

Also, try not to just copy sketches (programs), but understand them. And than adapt them a bit, make variations on the component 'tests'.

I have a whole folder where I test each component with Arduino (and for some complicated components multiple sketches). Save them, and add links etc, so you can easily reference back to it.

You can use books, but there is so much information for the Arduino that this forum, the official web site and google should be enough to get you going.

(note: for the Arduino I did not use books, since as above said, there is so much information. I'm now diving in to STM32 which is more complex and a book/PDF is more convenient).